# How to block all incoming calls if number is not stored in contact list?

Tags: call-sms-filter

How to block all incoming calls (and messages) that are not from the contacts in my contact list? Basically I just want to white list my contacts (and black list some of them). I couldn't find such functionality in standard call filter application or Truecaller. Is it possible to do so on Windows 10 mobile?

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you could use 'Quiet Hours' feature and filter the ones which you want to receive calls/messages from. since it is not possible to block all incoming calls.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is currently not possible to block all unknown numbers. For now you'll have to manually block each call you want to ignore.